# Power static is not working using PowerMockito.mockstatic(*.class)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Not mocking static class while doing below code .I am not sure why its failing .
Can you please help me on this.

```
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({AppConfig.class,UserPeer.class, WebLogDataSourceServiceImpl.class, DataJurisdictionLoader.class})
    public class WebLogDataSourceServiceImplTest {
    @Test
        public void isAdminOrUserManager() throws Exception {
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(UserPeer.class);
            Mockito.when(UserPeer.retrieveByPK(anyInt())).thenReturn(user);
            when(user.getRoleIds()).thenReturn(roleIds);
            boolean isAdminManager = service.isAdminOrUserManager(userId);
            assertEquals(isAdminManager, true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you format your code so that it is readable to others?

Comment: You should include the class under test as well. Also when you say its failing what exactly do you mean? If you have a stacktrace add it and point out the related line(s).

Comment: failing means it should mock the class and return the value but its calling actual class method there its connecting databases so its throwing exception

Comment: executing maven goal is org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent

Comment: Use another statement like `doReturn(user).when(UserPeer.retrieveByPK(anyInt()));`